# Calculating rectangle corners location in rotating around a pivot line

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm trying to transform shapes in an Android app by rotating them around a pivot line (using [View.setRotationY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationY(float))). As you see in the below images, I rotate the shape around the green line which is parallel to the vertical axis and crossed the center point of the rect. Looking at its 2D drawing makes sense that the left edge comes forward and the right edge goes backward.
Now I want to formulate it. I mean the length of the edges based on rotation angle as well as their movement.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

**Rotation Angle: 0°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 15°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 30°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 45°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 60°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 75°**

[image]

**Rotation Angle: 90°**

[image]

Comment: The vertices follow two ellipses which you can parametrize as $(a\cos(t)+x_0, b\sin(t)+y_0)$, where $t$ is the angle in radians, and $a>0,b>0,x_0=0,y_0$ are constants that depend on how far the square is from the camera, and the focal length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a square of sides 2 units, the spatial coordinates of the four vertices are

$$(x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta,s,r\sin\theta)$$ where the $r$ and $s$ are $\pm1$ independently, and $\theta$ is the rotation angle around the vertical axis ($y$).

Now their perspective projection, assuming the viewpoint at $f$ units in the direction of the $z$ axis is

$$(X,Y)=\left(\frac{fx}{z+f},\frac{fy}{z+f}\right)=\left(\frac{fr\cos\theta}{r\sin\theta+f},\frac{fs}{r\sin\theta+f}\right).$$

[image]

Comment: It correctly maps the points and works like a charm :)

Comment: After the rotation, if I want to scale the resulting shape without changing the camera distance (I mean I want to scale the shape such that the left edge length multiplied with **$\alpha$**), how much do I need to scale **r** and **s** to achieve this? Thanks for the previous help. I appreciate it!

Comment: @aminography: you can figure this out for yourself. What are the 3D coordinates of the corners ?

Comment: I imagined it, but I couldn't reach the right formula.

Comment: @aminography: try again. What are the 3D coordinates of the corners ?

Comment: Imagine the corner at (-1, 1, 0). by rotating it, the 2D mapping goes to (-1.32, 1.54) for $\theta=30$ and some **f** parameter. Now, I want to find **r** and **s** which moves the 2D mapping to (-0.66, 0.77) which means scale down the 2D mapping by $\alpha = 0.5$. It's obvious that the latent scale factor is related to $\theta$, **f**, and $\alpha$. Is it true?

Comment: @aminography: forget the rotation and you will see that the answer is obvious.

Comment: I know. The combination of rotation and scaling is the problem.

Comment: @aminography: no, it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have found the problem. The problem comes from the Android View camera distance when we combine scale and rotation transformations.

Answer (score -1):

Assume the edge length at zero angle is $a$ and the edge length at 90-degree angle is $b$, you may formulate the edge length as function of the rotation angle $\theta$ as,

$$L(\theta) = b\sin\theta + a(1-\sin\theta)$$

Such a relationship is based on the assumption that the edge length varies linearly with respect to the front-back distance.